# iPhone screen shifts when entering foreground

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I've noticed that when my iPhone app enters the foreground after being suspended on an iPad2 (iOS version 4.3.3), the iPhone screen seems to shift up by a small amount after a split second.  My understanding is that iOS takes a snapshot of the screen before suspending the app so it can quickly bring it back up when resuming, but it's not clear to me why it would be shifted. The status bar placeholder and iPhone image don't shift up, only the rest of the iPhone screen does.  I don't see this problem in the 5.0 simulator.

Any ideas what's going on or how to fix this?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When the app loads, it displays the default.png file that you have in your app bundle. If you have this image the same as whatever the first screen of your app is (which apple suggests that you should do) then it is displaying this image, and then the actual screen once the app is done initializing. You can edit the png file by shifting up a pixel or two (you'll just have to guess and check to see exactly what you need).

The other possibility is that your default.png isnt the right size, so it is being resized when the app actually starts. Check that the dimensions are correct for the device you are testing on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Initially, I thought it was the default.png too, but this happens for any screen in my app when I press the Home button to suspend the app and then later resume it.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the status bat to initially hidden caused this for me.

> Status bar is initially hidden  YES

This fixed it

```
- (void) setStatusBarVisible: (NSTimer *)timer 
{
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];

     [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(setStatusBarVisible:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
 }
```

It appears that setting then reseting (after a short delay) the status bar addresses this issue.

This fixes it but it shouldn't happen in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

yes it happens when you come again to foreground. it happens with me & i have solved this issue by using

```
 (void)layoutSubviews
```

that means i draws the things  in layoutSubviews method which shifts & it works fine.

for more information on this [check my problem & solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331432/application-life-cycle-issue/14357154#14357154)