# application life cycle issue

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar, lifecycle

i have made changes in navigation bar means i have increasd the height of navigation bar & made some custom changes,it works fine but when i minimizes the application and again maximize it, it shows only original height that is what changes i made, those not works after minimization, my code is

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSLog(@" i m in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" );



    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TopHeader"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 55)];   

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:(-15.0) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                           [UIColor colorWithRed:245.0/255.0 green:245.0/255.0 blue:245.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                                           [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8],UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                                           [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 1)],
                                                           UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                                                           [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack" size:16.0], UITextAttributeFont, nil]];

return YES;  
}
```

after maximize it goes to `applicationDidBecomeActive` thats why i put above code in `applicationDidBecomeActive` but its not working, why this is happening?
before minimize
[image]
after minimize & maximize again it looks like below i.e. height again automatically sets to 44.
[image]

Update: i written following code in   `applicationWillEnterForeground`

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{    
    UINavigationController *my=(UINavigationController *  )self.window.rootViewController;

    UINavigationBar *navigationBar = [my navigationBar];
    CGRect frame = [navigationBar frame];
    frame.size.height = 55.0f;
    [navigationBar setFrame:frame];

    NSLog(@" i m in applicationWillEnterForeground" );

   }
```

at the time of debugging when i writes its description it shows that height is 55. but on screen it still looks like second image. why this is happening.

Comment: Downvoter plz care to comment? unnecessarily downvoting not a good thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem, just overrides the UINavigationBar & in LayoutSubViews set the height of navigationBar.

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (customNAvigBar)

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [self setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 55)];
}

@end
```

that means whenever i draws the navigationBar it calls automatically & sets the height.

Answer (score 4):

When your app opens from the background `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` does not get called. You want to use either `applicationWillEnterForeground:` or `applicationDidBecomeActive:` instead. Check out the `UIApplicationDelegate` [protocol reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for more information.

---

**EDIT:** In response to the question author's edits, I will say this. I played around with this code in an app of mine, and I've been able to reproduce the problem. I've tried a number of solutions to fix it, including resetting the frame of the navbar in a `UINavigationController`'s `layoutSubviews`. I suggest creating a sample project that reproduces this issue and submitting it to Apple's Bug reporter, or creating a UINavigationBar subclass that repositions and resizes itself.

Comment: Not working in the sense that the method is not being called, or not working in the sense that the navigation bar height is wrong?

Comment: method is calling, i m checking through NSLOg, height is working when it is in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOption

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted? Anyways, I have been able to reproduce this behavior in an app I've been working on. I haven't been able to modify the navbar height after the initial app launch. This is starting to point to an Apple bug.